# Is it necessary to set onload function before setting src for an image object?

Tags: javascript, html, image

I was told it is necessary to set the `onload` function before setting `src` for an image object. I've [searched in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=image%20src%20onload) for this.

I found this code:

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = 'image.jpg';
img.onload = function () {
    document.body.appendChild(img);
};
```

But most people believe that `onload` should be written before `src` like this:

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function () {
    document.body.appendChild(img);
};
img.src = 'image.jpg';
```

**MUST** it be written in this order? Are there any cases when the above code will cause an error (like if an image is too big)?

If you anyone can show me some examples, I will be very appreciate.

Comment: I guess IE bugs out on this one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As soon as you assign the src a value, the image will load. If it loads before the onload is reached, your onload will not fire.

To support ALL implementations, I strongly suggest to assign the onload handler before setting the src.

It is my experience (21+ years of JS) that you MUST set onload first - especially in IE which did not even support the image object when I started with JS.

If you get issues about the cached image not firing, add `+"?"+new Date().getTime()` when you set the src next time to avoid cache.

Here is the example from MDN which also uses the order I have suggested

[Creating an image from scratch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Canvas_tutorial/Using_images#Creating_an_image_from_scratch)

Another SO link [image.onload not firing twice in IE7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038327/image-onload-not-firing-twice-in-ie7)

Comment: what do you think about this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7552629/can-onload-event-fire-right-after-setting-image-src-attribute

Comment: I my many years experience with JS (more years than the image object existed) the onload MUST be before the src is set. In all browsers I have used it works. In MANY browsers I have used it does not work the other way around and it is not until today in Chrome I saw it working in your fiddle

Comment: I believe this way can avoid many issues, though the other way works in some case. So I would accept you post.

Comment: I think the answer is that although implementations differ between browsers, you **must** set the `onload` first if you want it to behave consistently.

Answer (score 9):

It doesn't have to, but if setting the `src` and the image loads before your handler is attached, it won't fire.

JavaScript operates asynchronously. Setting the `src` will cause the web browser to load the image outside the main execution flow. If `onload` isn't set at the time that operation completes - which could be between setting `src` and `onload`.

Comment: Could the load event happen during script execution? Note the code sample does not return between setting the handler and the source.

Comment: I can't understand clear, could you explain it more detailed？

Comment: Is it that JavaScript runs async? Or that it sometimes runs unexpectedly sync?  As @JanDvorak suggests, if you're talking async, the expectation would be that the onload would run on the next frame, not in the middle of the executing script. I honestly do not know, so I'm asking, but it *seems* like the onload might be fired sync by some browsers if the image is already loaded, hence the need to define it first.

Comment: E.g. [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cP5qy/) (obviously not how `Image.src=` is defined, but illustrates what I mean), even though the `onload` is fired with an immediate timeout, it still fires when defined after.

Comment: what do you think about this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7552629/can-onload-event-fire-right-after-setting-image-src-attribute

Answer (score 2):

The browser will start downloading the image asychronously as soon as you assign a src, so there is the possibility the download could complete before you attach the onload event handler and never fire the code to add the image to the DOM.

Answer (score 2):

Most browser fire the load event imediatly if the image if the image is cached.
However, Internet explorer 7 won't fire it at all. That's why it's better to set the src first.

Comment: Not in my experience at all! - this one backs me up http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038327/image-onload-not-firing-twice-in-ie7

Comment: It says exactly what i'm saying ...
"t's caused because IE will cache the image, and the onload event will never fire after it's already been loaded."

Comment: It does not follow that it is better to set src first. If you need it to run again, you just set the src to something + "?"+new Date().getTime() or similar

Answer (score 1):

Answers above always mentioned the same problem like:

> there is the possibility the download could complete before you attach the onload event handler

or

> but if setting the src and the image loads before your handler is attached, it won't fire.

or bug with IE7.

First, let's ignore IE7.

Second, I don't think problem mentioned exist, for example:

```js
function loadImg(url) {
  let img = new Image()
  img.src = url
  let date1 = Date.now()
  console.log(img.complete)
  while (Date.now() - date1 < 5000) {

  }
  img.onload = function() {
    console.log('success')
  }
  console.log('sync first')
}
loadImg('https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/sprites.svg')
```

Normally, you will get:

```
false
sync first
success
```

Well, if you executed on another site which will use cache more than one time. You will get the result like image below:

[image]

The answer is clear now.

**Well, as long as you set the `onload` synchronously. You will not miss the `onload` event.**

Why would I say `synchronously`. For another example,

```js
function loadImg(url) {
  let img = new Image()
  img.src = url
  let date1 = Date.now()
  console.log(img.complete)
  while (Date.now() - date1 < 5000) {
  
   }
  setTimeout(function() {
    img.onload = function() {
      console.log('success')
    }
  })

  console.log('sync first')
}
loadImg('https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/sprites.svg')
```

The result on another site:

[image]

The second time with cache, `load` event won't be triggered. And the reason is `setTimeout` is asynchronously.

Comment: So that code could also fail?  `img.src = url; await new Promise(function (res) { img.onload = res; });`