# Loading an image onto a canvas with javaScript

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am currently testing using the `<canvas>` element to draw all of the backgrounds (I will add effects later to these images later and is the reason I'm not using CSS to load the images). That said, I'm currently having difficulty loading a image on to the canvas. Here is the code:

```
<html>    
<head>    
    <title>Canvas image testing</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function Test1() {
            var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas');
            if (canvas.getContext) {
                var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
                //Loading of the home test image - img1
                var img1 = new Image();
                img1.src = 'img/Home.jpg';
                //drawing of the test image - img1
                img1.onload = function () {
                    //draw background image
                    ctx.drawimage(img1, 0, 0);
                    //draw a box over the top
                    ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(200, 0, 0, 0.5)";
                    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
                };
            }                
        }
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        canvas { border: 2px solid black; width: 100%; height: 98%; }
    </style>
</head>
<body onload="Test1();">    
    <canvas id="canvas" width="1280" height="720"></canvas>      
</body>
</html>
```

I think that I'm not loading the image correctly, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 36):

There are a few things:

1. `drawimage` should be `drawImage` - note the capital i.
2. Your `getElementById` is looking for an element with ID of `canvas`, but it should be `test1`. `canvas` is the tag, not the ID.
3. Replace the `canvas` variable (e.g. in your `canvas.getContext` lines) with `ctx`, since that's the variable you've used to select your canvas element.
4. Bind your `onload` handler before you set the `src` of the image.

So your function should end up like this:

```
function Test1() {
    var ctx = document.getElementById('test1');
    if (ctx.getContext) {

        ctx = ctx.getContext('2d');

        //Loading of the home test image - img1
        var img1 = new Image();

        //drawing of the test image - img1
        img1.onload = function () {
            //draw background image
            ctx.drawImage(img1, 0, 0);
            //draw a box over the top
            ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(200, 0, 0, 0.5)";
            ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 500, 500);

        };

        img1.src = 'img/Home.jpg';
    }
}
```

Comment: freejosh is right - but I just wanted to add that it is not very good style to use the variable `ctx` for the canvas and override it with the context later. You could use `var canvas` for the canvas reference.

Comment: One question, why do we have to set image source after onload event?

Comment: @AlyssaGono I think [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14648626/1399979) is a good explanation.

Answer (score 32):

Using newer JavaScript features:

```
let img = await loadImage("./my/image/path.jpg");
ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
```

and the `loadImage` function looks like this:

```
async function loadImage(url) {
  return new Promise(r => { let i = new Image(); i.onload = (() => r(i)); i.src = url; });
}
```

Comment: The first line reports "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word"

Comment: @Omiod You have to enclose this code inside an `async` function.

Comment: Note that it might be useful to also `reject` the promise if the image doesn't load, otherwise this could hang without you noticing. `new Promise((r,e) => { ... i.onerror = error => e(error); ... i.src = src; }`

Answer (score 7):

move the onload event listener to before you set the src for the image.

```
    var img1 = new Image();

    //drawing of the test image - img1
    img1.onload = function () {
        //draw background image
        ctx.drawImage(img1, 0, 0);
        //draw a box over the top
        ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(200, 0, 0, 0.5)";
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 500, 500);

    };

    img1.src = 'img/Home.jpg';
```

Answer (score 6):

Assign your local file resource (url) to image source and draw image using context from canvas you want to load. That's it. See code bellow.

```
var loadImage = function (url, ctx) {
  var img = new Image();
  img.src = url
  img.onload = function () { 
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
   var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
   var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
   var img1 = new Image();

    //drawing of the test image - img1
    img1.onload = function () {
        //draw background image
        ctx.drawImage(img1, 0, 0);
        //draw a box over the top
        ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(200, 0, 0, 0.5)";
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 500, 500);

    };

    img1.src = 'img/Home.jpg';
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```