# I want to add image in javascript

Tags: javascript

**i want to add image using javascript but it is not working**

> html code:

```
<body onload="init()">
    <canvas id="canvas" width="640" height="480">
        <p>your browser doesnot support html5 canvas.</p>
    </canvas>
    <script src="script.js">
    </script>
</body>
```

**and this is javascript:**

```
var canvas;
var context;

function init() {
    canvas = document.getElementById("canvas")
    context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    console.log("loading comepletd");
    var image = new Image();
    image.src = "ball.png";
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you expecting to happen? You're creating an instance of an image but you aren't doing anything with it.

Comment: you forgot a semi-colon after the getElementById()

And you can you the JS console to debug your code ;) (F12)

Comment: i want to show this image in my browser. That's all i want to do!

Comment: can you please fix that code!

Comment: The phrase: "Not working" is going to invite downvotes.  We are not mind-readers.  Tell us what you expected to happen and what actually happened.

Comment: @Pierre Technically the semicolon isn't required but it's definitely a good idea to be consistent.

Comment: @suzan If all you want is to show an image in your browser then you can just do `<img src="ball.png">` but based on your code, it looks like you're trying to make a game or animation.

Comment: Why are you using canvas?

Comment: @MikeC : ok I didn't know :)

Comment: Duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14757659/loading-an-image-onto-a-canvas-with-javascript - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6011378/how-to-add-image-to-canvas

Comment: @Damon! nothing important just practicing!

Comment: @Mike C i want to show image as well as do some coding on that image like movement and stuff does <img> tag work for that

Comment: @suzan Yes and no. Look at the links posted by mplungjan. They'll get you started.

Comment: You will have a lot of learning, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement

Comment: thanks @Teemu i have solved my problem! and thanks all of you who help me to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
var canvas;
var context;

function init() {
    canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    console.log("loading comepletd");
    var image = new Image();
    image.src = "ball.png";
    image.onload = function(){
        context.drawImage(image, 100, 100);
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6011378/how-to-add-image-to-canvas

Comment: Please delete your answer instead of copying the code from the link I posted

Comment: @kanayo austin kane this worked for me!

Comment: @suzan. Am happy it worked. Please mark it as answered and don't forget to upvote

Comment: i am new at stackoverflow so i don't know so much about marking etc,etc

Comment: Lol, @suzan but you have done that already

Comment: You can upvote by clicking the triangle above the number

Comment: Now i know about marking the correct answer and upvote

Comment: Lol... But you haven't upvoted my answer