# async await in image loading

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, async-await

**Temp.js**

```
export default class Temp {
    async addImageProcess(src){
        let img = new Image();
        img.src = src;
        return img.onload = await function(){
          return this.height;
        }
    }
}
```

**anotherfile.js**

```
import Temp from '../../classes/Temp'
let tmp = new Temp()

imageUrl ="https://www.google.co.in/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_120x44dp.png"
let image = tmp.addImageProcess(imageUrl);
console.log(image)
```

Above is my code. I have a image url and tried to get image's properties using async await but it's not working, don't understand what I missed.

Answer (score 120, accepted):

Your problem here extends from [the definition for `await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await)...

> The `await` operator is used to wait for a `Promise`

The `Image.prototype.onload` property is not a promise, nor are you assigning it one. If you're wanting to return the `height` property after loading, I would instead create a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)...

```
addImageProcess(src){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let img = new Image()
    img.onload = () => resolve(img.height)
    img.onerror = reject
    img.src = src
  })
}
```

You would then use the following to access that value

```
tmp.addImageProcess(imageUrl).then(height => {
  console.log(height)
})
```

or, if within an `async` function

```
async function logImageHeight(imageUrl) {
  console.log('height', await tmp.addImageProcess(imageUrl))
}
```

Comment: thanks @phil, now I understood. There is a small typo in addImageProcess.

Answer (score 95):

Previous answers are correct, but I  wanted to point out that there is now an [`HTMLImageElement.decode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/decode) method which almost corresponds to a Promisified onload handler.

This has the advantages of not needing to do the wrapping yourself, to handle already loaded images (previous answers fail this case), and to wait for the image to be actually decoded, which may be a good thing in various situation (e.g if you wanted to use it with the synchronous Canvas2DContext.`drawImage()` method, your script would get blocked while this decoding is done).

So now all it takes is

```js
(async () => {
  const img = new Image();
  img.src = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/47/PNG_transparency_demonstration_1.png";
  await img.decode();
  // img is ready to use
  console.log( `width: ${ img.width }, height: ${ img.height }` );
})();
```

Comment: Note for those who are looking to use this, decode() is incompatible with IE

Comment: @stor314 and IE is incompatible with humans.

Comment: @AkshayKNair i agree, wish clients would understand that

Comment: this perfectly solved my problems, all my thanks

Comment: This is the cleanest way to achieve async await with images loading in modern browsers, thanks @adrianosmateus

Answer (score 20):

While the proposed solution works perfect, I want to be able to avoid writing promises for every asynchronous function, so I wrote a generic utility function just for this purpose:

in javascript

```
function onload2promise(obj){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        obj.onload = () => resolve(obj);
        obj.onerror = reject;
    });
}
```

in typescript (including some generic typechecks):

```
interface OnLoadAble {
   onload: any;
}
function onload2promise<T extends OnLoadAble>(obj: T): Promise<T> {
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   obj.onload = () => resolve(obj);
   obj.onerror = reject;
 });
}
```

In the example of the question, you can now do:

```
async function addImageProcess(src){
    let img = new Image();
    let imgpromise = onload2promise(img); // see comment of T S why you should do it this way.
    img.src = src;
    await imgpromise;
    return this.height;
}
```

Off course, the call in **anotherfile.js** should still happen asynchronously as well, as explained in the last codeblock of Phils answer

Comment: The Promise never rejects. Set `onerror`: `function onload2promise(obj){
    return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
        obj.onload = () => resolve(obj);
        obj.onerror = reject;
    });
}`

Comment: Your method is slightly dangerous: It sets `onload` after image loading started. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14648598/is-it-necessary-to-set-onload-function-before-setting-src-for-an-image-object

Comment: Good remarks, I think I updated the answer to fix the issues you mentioned!

Comment: Nice! Some more thoughts: Should `onabort` also reject the Promise? The `interface OnLoadAble` should contain `onerror` (and `onabort` if added as reject event). In your last Codeblock, did you mean `return img.height;`?