# Problem with drawing image on canvas after loading it with fetch and async/await

Tags: javascript, canvas, async-await, fetch-api, bloburls

I tried to load image using fetch and async/await and display it on canvas, but it doesn't work. The image isn't drawn on canvas. It loads correctly into img element in HTML. On canvas if I wrap the drawing code in setTimeout it works, but I would prefer to not to do this.

Is there some way to load the image using await and fetch and draw it on canvas without setTimeout?

Here is the code:

```js
async function loadImage(url) {
    let response = await fetch(url);
    let blob = await response.blob();
    return URL.createObjectURL(blob);
}

let canvas = document.body.querySelector("canvas");
let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

let tileURL = loadImage("https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/92330684?s=120&v=4").then((tileURL) => {
        
    // Displaying image element in HTML works.
    let img = document.body.querySelector("img");
    img.src = tileURL;
    
    // Displaying the image immediately in canvas doesn't work.
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    
    // But it works if I add some delay.
    setTimeout(() => {
         ctx.drawImage(img, 100, 0);
    }, 3000); // 3 second delay.
    
});
```

```css
canvas {
   border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
<img>
```

Comment: There's no reason to assign `let tileURL` to the promise returned by `loadImage`. You never use it (not an answer, just an observation)

Comment: You might want to make `loadImage` return an `Image`, not an object url

Comment: @Bergi OP would need to [manually create a `Promise`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46399452/283366) then to handle the loading which IMO won't make the code any nicer

Comment: @Phil It would make the drawing code nicer - not the `loadImage` code, yes.

Comment: TIL about [HTMLImageElement.decode()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/decode) thanks to [this awesome answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64747517/283366)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loading an image is always asynchronous, whatever the source*. You need to wait for it has loaded before being able to do anything with it.

Now, it's unclear why you are using `fetch` here, you can very well just set the image's `.src` to the URL directly:

```js
const canvas = document.body.querySelector("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

// Displaying image element in HTML works.
const img = document.body.querySelector("img");
img.crossOrigin = "anonymous"; // allow read-back
img.src = "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/92330684?s=120&v=4";
img.onload = (evt) => // or await img.decode() if in async
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
```

```css
canvas {
   border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
<img>
```

However, if you have a Blob (or are actually forced to use `fetch`), then create an [ImageBitmap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageBitmap) from this Blob directly. This is the most performant way to produce and store a CanvasImageSource (to be used in `drawImage()`).
For older browsers that didn't support this method, I got you covered through [this polyfill of mine](https://github.com/Kaiido/createImageBitmap).

```js
async function loadImage(url) {
  const response = await fetch(url);
  const blob = response.ok && await response.blob();
  return createImageBitmap(blob);
}

const canvas = document.body.querySelector("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
loadImage("https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/92330684?s=120&v=4").then((bitmap) => {
  ctx.drawImage(bitmap, 0, 0);
});
```

```css
canvas {
   border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<!-- createImageBitmap polyfill for old browsers --> <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/Kaiido/createImageBitmap/dist/createImageBitmap.js"></script>
<canvas></canvas>
<!-- HTMLImage is not needed -->
```

*<sup>It may happen that cached images are ready before the next call to `drawImage()`, but one should never assume so.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Even though you're using an in-memory blob URL, it still needs to be loaded by the browser.

You aren't waiting for the `img` to load before adding it to the canvas so all it adds is a blank.

Register a *load* event handler or use the newer [HTMLImageElement.decode()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/decode) to wait for the image to be ready before adding it to the canvas.

```js
async function loadImage(url) {
  let response = await fetch(url);
  let blob = await response.blob();
  return URL.createObjectURL(blob);
}

const img = document.querySelector("img");
const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

const url = "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/92330684?s=120&v=4"

loadImage(url).then(async (tileURL) => {

  // Displaying image element in HTML works.
  img.src = tileURL;
  
  // wait for it to load
  await img.decode()
  
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
});
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
<img>
```