# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'img' of undefined

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to add sprites to my game engine and I've tried a whole bunch of things. The problem is that the game can run but my image never shows.
EDIT: I have found by putting the image and src in the coin class constructor makes it render.

I've tried window.onLoad, img.onLoad, putting the vars in the constructor, splitting it into 2 functions (load and draw).

```
class gameObject {
    constructor(x,y,id){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.id = id;
        var velX, velY, width, height;
    }
    drawRect(){
        c.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
    }
    drawSprite(url){

            this.img = new Image();
            this.img.src = url;
            this.img.onload = function(){
                function draw(){
                    c.drawImage(this.img, this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height)
                }
                draw();
            }
    }
    move(){
        this.x += this.velX;
        this.y += this.velY;
    }
}
class Coin extends gameObject{
        constructor(x,y,id,img){
            super(x,y,id);
            this.velX = 0;
            this.velY = 0;
            this.width = 32;
            this.height = 32;
        }
        tick(){
            this.move();
        }
        render(){
            this.drawSprite("coin.png");
        }
    }
```

I need the image to show but it doesn't show and the game still runs.

Comment: Trying setting the onload before setting the src.  This may be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14648598/is-it-necessary-to-set-onload-function-before-setting-src-for-an-image-object

Comment: change `this.img.onload = function(){` to `this.img.onload = () => {` or bind the correct  `this` to it - you need to know how `this` works especially in asynchronous callbacks

Comment: also, why are you doing `function draw(){
                    c.drawImage(this.img, this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height)
                }
                draw();` ... seems unnecessary

Answer (score 1):

As per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this), the value of `this` is `undefined` in `function draw` because it's a nested function inside a class declaration - and class declarations are parsed in strict mode.

One solution is to

- use an arrow function for `draw` so it captures the lexical `this` value when it is assigned to a variable,
- place the arrow function expression where the `this` value refers to the class instance instead of the image element, and
- assign image `onload` handlers before setting their `src` attribute:

```
drawSprite(url){
    let draw = ()=>c.drawImage(this.img, this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
    this.img = new Image();
    this.img.onload = draw;
    this.img.src = url;
}
```

Further testing showed that CanvasRenderingContext2D method `drawImage` can not handle undefined values for x and y, and will draw nothing if they are.

```
class gameObject {
    constructor(x,y,id){
        this.x = x || 0; // default x and y to zero
        this.y = y || 0;
        this.id = id;
        var velX, velY, width, height;
    }
```

Defaulting undefined values to zero should help gettting further along with development.

Comment: This works to get rid of the error but the image still does not show up.

Comment: Undefined values for x and y arguments stop `drawImage` from producing output.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so the only solution I found was to move this.img & this.img.src to the class as shown here

```
class Coin extends gameObject{
    constructor(x,y,id){
        super(x,y,id);
        this.velX = 0;
        this.velY = 0;
        this.width = 32;
        this.height = 32;
        this.img = new Image();
        this.img.src = "coin.png";
    }
    tick(){
        this.move();
    }
    render(){
        this.drawSprite()
    }
}
```

and also apparently when waiting for the img to load also causes it to not show up so i just did this.

```
drawSprite(){
    c.drawImage(this.img, this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
}
```

I am also keeping it as the draw sprite function because I am going to make it also read from sprite sheets