# Protractor: Setting variables

Tags: javascript, protractor

Still fairly new to Protractor. I'm trying to set the variable text but it returns the empty string. Explanations and fixes are greatly appreciated!

I tried debugging by adding "listname " to be printed to the console. It works fine but the text is not printed to the console.

```
var listname = "";

selectList()
    .first()
    .element(by.css('.listname'))
    .getText()
    .then(function(text) { 
        listname = text;
        console.log(listname);
    });

console.log("listname " + listname);
```

From my understanding, I know that this should be asynchronous, but I thought the promise is fulfilled by the .then . Afterwards I should be able to retrieve the text.

The return output is:

```
listname 

List1
```

Whereas I expect:

```
List1

listname List1
```

Comment: `.then()` sets a *callback* for when the asynchronous code is done.  It does not fulfill/resolve the promise.

Answer (score 1):

If it was blocking console.log then it wouldn't have been asynchronous. `console.log` gets executed *before* your promise is resolved. Therefore below gets printed first.

```
listname 

List1
```

Check fantastic answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3939315/are-callbacks-always-asynchronous)

Answer (score 0):

It is asynchronous, so it is not sure to the first `console.log` will runs before the second `console log`.